# Access an ActiveRecord association without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We're splitting up a Rails project. Some data, which used to be an Active Record model, is now accessed through an external API.  Is there an easy way to keep all original associations working?

For example, we started with a typical:

```
 class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bar
 end
```

but now `Bar` is no longer in our DB. So to access a `Foo` from `Bar`, we'd have to call `Foo.where(bar_id:bar.id)` or `Foo.find(bar_id:bar.id)`, depending on OTM or MTM, where we used to be able to call `bar.foos` or `bar.foo`.

What is a good way to do this?  Is there an easy way to provide all the has_many relationship methods when Bar is no longer an ActiveRecord model?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `bar` object with an `#id` method, why not just recreate the association by defining a `foo` instance method in that objects class like so?

```
class Bar

  # OTM example
  def foo
    Foo.where(bar_id: self.id)
  end

end
```

Comment: At scale, this is very repeated behaviour. There's handful of associations for each one, and we're doing this to about a half dozen classes intertwined throughout the app.

I was playing with a `acts_like_relation_concern`, but I'd have to a concern for each class involved. ActiveRecord abstracts this completely, just has a database dependency.